# Unable to click at hyperlink on webpage with anchor tag

Tags: html, excel, vba, internet-explorer, href

After testing of different logic's, finally I stuck in *Visual Basic for Applications* to find out the right way to trigger the below attribute:

[image]
I want to click on hyperlink which does not remain same, it shows different numbers with hyperlink on every next attempt and below is my VBA code:

```
Dim MyBrowser As InternetExplore
Dim MyHTML_Element As IHTMLElement
Dim myURL As String

Dim htmlInput As HTMLInputElement
Dim htmlColl As IHTMLElementCollection
Dim p As String
Dim link As Object
Dim I As Integer
Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim doc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

myURL = "url............."
Set MyBrowser = New InternetExplorer
MyBrowser.Silent = True
MyBrowser.navigate myURL
MyBrowser.Visible = True
Do
Loop Until MyBrowser.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set HTMLDoc = MyBrowser.Document

If htmldoc.all.item(i).innerText = Range("K20").Value Then  ' Range is equal to cell value "4000123486736"
   htmldoc.all.item(i).Click            <------- not woking both lines
```

Please also see inspects on IE appended below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Of course this cannot work

```
If htmldoc.all.item(i).innerText = Range("K20").Value Then  ' Range is equalto cell value "4000123486736"
   htmldoc.all.item(i).Click            <------- not woking both lines
```

because there is no loop that defines `i`.

I suggest to loop through all link tags `<a>` only:

```
Dim LinkItem As Variant
For Each LinkItem In HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("a")
    If LinkItem.innerText = Range("K20").Value Then
        LinkItem.Click
        Exit For 'stop looping when link was found
    End If
Next LinkItem
```

Comment: Thanks PEH, but these codes are not working to click on link and even it is not indicating any error as well  :{

Comment: @samm Please debug your code going through it step-by-step (F8) and see if it finds the tag with its specific value and if it reaches the step `LinkItem.Click`. Also make sure you don't use `On Error Resume Next` anywhere in your code.

Comment: @PEH Giving runtime error '70': Permission Denied, when I debug my code. :(

Comment: @samm well in which line? You need to be much more descriptive I don't have a crystal ball where I can see everything.

Comment: @PEH, it is highlighting below line of instructions:

         "If LinkItem.innerText = Range("K20").Value Then"

Comment: @samm Probably you need to specify a worksheet for your `Range` like `Worksheets("YourSheet").Range(…)`